# Excel: Macro to add Row name and column headers to row when column = yes

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I've got a list of users and groups in an Excel file that's structured like this:

Sample base data:

[image]

I need to convert this into an upload file that consists of two columns. The result should list the username in column A and the Group Name in Column B for each time there is a YES value.

Expected output:

[image]

I've looked at PowerQuery, but I'm a bit lost here as to how to approach this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts from `A1` and result will display on `E1`. Try below sub-

```
Sub reGroup()
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long, lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each r In Range("A2:A" & lRow)
    For i = 1 To 3
        If r.Offset(0, i) = "yes" Then
            Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = r
            Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Cells(1, i + 1)
        End If
    Next i
Next r

End Sub
```

[image]